# Vim regex searching: alter placement of cursor in matched strings

Tags: regex, vim, cursor-position, text-cursor

I frequently use the vim regex `/\.` (note the trailing space) as a quick and (very) dirty way to identify new sentences. I would like the cursor to jump to the space, rather than the period when I type `n` or `N`.

Generally, how can I control the placement of the cursor in regex matches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define where the match should start with `\zs` (see `:help \zs`), so `/\. \zs` would leave the cursor on the first letter of the next sentence (ie. equivalent to the `)` sentence motion) and `/\.\zs` (note trailing space) would leave it on the space.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `/e` flag to position the cursor on the last character of the match:

```
/\. /e
```

But you already have "sentence" motions, `(` and `)` so… why bother?